# Совместное использование сигналов и каналов

Tags: c

Никак не могу разобраться как решить задачу на совместное использование сигналов и каналов (пинг-понг) .
Вот условие:

> Написать программу игры в "пинг-понг" двух процессов через один канал.
>   Первый процесс посылает второму 1, второй первому – 2, первый второму
>   – 3, второй первому – 4 и т.д. Для синхронизации использовать сигнал.
>   Игра завершается при нажатии клавиш Ctrl+C.

Вот мой код:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

int cnt=0;

int main(){
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    if(fork()==0){
        write(fd[1],&cnt,sizeof(int));
        while(read(fd[0],&cnt,sizeof(int))){//Дочерний процесс начинает пинг-понг
            printf("%d\n",cnt);
            cnt++;
            write(fd[1],&cnt,sizeof(int));
        }
        close(fd[1]);
        close(fd[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    while(read(fd[0],&cnt,sizeof(int))){
        printf("%d\n",cnt);
        write(fd[1],&cnt,sizeof(int));
    }
    close(fd[1]);
    close(fd[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А в чем вопрос, проблема: не собирается, падает, работает не так как задумывалось?.

Comment: Не знаю как использовать для синхронизации сигналы

Comment: Почитайте [man sigsuspend](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigsuspend). Там в Notes рассказано, как синхронизировать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поскольку процессы должны общаться через **один** канал, а канал имеет некоторый буфер, позволяющий писать несколько байт без читающего, процесс вызывающий `read` после `write` может прочитать собственные данные, в чём легко убедиться запустив немного исправленную вашу программу:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

int cnt=0;

int main(){
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    if(fork()==0){
        printf("2 w%d\n",cnt);
        write(fd[1],&cnt,sizeof(int));
        while(cnt<100 && read(fd[0],&cnt,sizeof(int))){//Дочерний процесс начинает пинг-понг
            printf("2 r%d\n",cnt);
            cnt++;
            printf("2 w%d\n",cnt);
            write(fd[1],&cnt,sizeof(int));
        }
        close(fd[1]);
        close(fd[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    while(cnt<100 && read(fd[0],&cnt,sizeof(int))){
        printf("1 r%d\n",cnt);
        cnt++;
        printf("1 w%d\n",cnt);
        write(fd[1],&cnt,sizeof(int));
    }
    close(fd[1]);
    close(fd[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Результаты:

```
$ ./a.out 
2 w0
1 r0
1 w1
1 r1
1 w2
1 r2
1 w3
1 r3
1 w4
1 r4
1 w5
1 r5
1 w6
1 r6
1 w7
1 r7
1 w8
1 r8
1 w9
1 r9
1 w10
```

Первый процесс сам справляется, а второй ему изредка помогает.
Необходимо чтобы каждый процесс после записи очередного числа ожидал готовности данных **для него**, блокирующее чтение тут не поможет, так как данные в канале уже есть.

Для ожидания можно бы использовать функцию `pause()`, но если сигнал придёт до входа в неё, это приведёт к бесконечному ожиданию, поэтому лучше `sleep(1)` в цикле с проверкой флага, который изменяется в функции-перехватчике сигнала.

Программа с обменом сигналами.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

int cnt=0;
int signaled=0;

void intr(int n) { // обработчик сигнала
  signaled=1;
}

int main(){
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    int pid;
    signal(SIGUSR1, intr);
    if((pid=fork())==0){ // Дочерний процесс начинает пинг-понг
        pid= getppid();
        printf("%d w%d\n",pid,cnt);
        kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
        write(fd[1],&cnt,sizeof(int));
    }
    while(1) {
        while(!signaled) sleep(1);
        if(read(fd[0],&cnt,sizeof(int))<=0) break;
        printf("%d r%d\n",pid,cnt);
        cnt++;
        printf("%d w%d\n",pid,cnt);
        signaled=0; // после kill в любом месте может прийти ответ, поэтому здесь обнуляем флаг
        signal(SIGUSR1, intr);
        kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
        write(fd[1],&cnt,sizeof(int));
    }
    close(fd[1]);
    close(fd[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Примечание. Иногда процессы приостанавливаются на одну секунду, это значит сигнал пришёл после проверки условия, но перед ожиданием сигнала внутри `sleep()`.

Comment: Игра завершается при нажатии клавиш Ctrl+C,а у вас,на сколько я понял,игра завершается при cnt>=100

Comment: @mango44 да, иначе слишком быстро экран заполняется

Comment: но по условию: Для синхронизации использовать сигнал. Игра завершается при нажатии клавиш Ctrl+C.

Comment: Эта задача на совместное использование сигналов и каналов

Comment: Этот пример иллюстрирует необходимость использовать сигналы и не является готовым решением задачи

Comment: Ну без сигналов(когда cnt) мы сами определяем я могу решить.А вот как с сигналами не знаю.Поэтому написал сюда

Comment: Добавил сигналы

Comment: А можите,пожалуйста,объяснить: зачем эта строчка signal(SIGALRM, intr);?

Comment: @mango44 ошибка, SIGUSR1 должно быть конечно, это я с другим номером сигнала пробовал и забыл исправить.  Хотя работает и вообще без неё, может пригодиться в зависимости от системы и настроек компилятора. Вообще лучше использовать sigaction, но лень.

Comment: В режиме совместимости с System V обработчик сбрасывается после сигнала и его надо заново устанавливать.

Comment: Все понял! Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Вот честное решение с синхронизацией только  обменом сигналами, без sleep-ов, глобальных переменных и потенциальных гонок (надеюсь (строго доказывать не собираюсь)).

Идея состоит в том, что мы получаем сигнал (т.е. разрешаем вызвать обработчик (на самом деле фиктивный, он ничего не делает)) в строго определенном месте кода (а именно в вызове [sigsuspend](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigsuspend)).

Это и есть точка синхронизации, в ней мы ждем "шарик от партнера". 
Все остальное время получение сигнала `SIGUSR1`, используемого для синхронизации блокируется. Для блокировки используется вызов [sigprocmask](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigprocmask) с маской, блокирующей `SIGUSR1`.

В самом начале  вызовом `sigprocmask` мы запоминаем текущую маску сигналов (она разрешает обработку `SIGUSR1`) и далее используем ее в `sigsuspend`. Маска сигналов наследуется новым процессом (после fork).

Впрочем, хватит разговоров, вот  код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <err.h>

void usr1 (int sig) { }

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  signal(SIGUSR1, usr1);
  sigset_t old, blocked;
  if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, 0, &old))
    err(-1, "sigprocmask get old"); // exit
  memcpy(&blocked, &old, sizeof(old));
  sigaddset(&blocked, SIGUSR1);
  if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &blocked, 0))
    err(-1, "sigprocmask set SIGUSR1"); // exit

  int fd[2], cnt = 0;
  pid_t pong;
  pipe(fd);

  if (pong = fork()) { // parent
    if (pong == -1)
      err(-1, "fork"); // exit
    // wait for a partner (child)
    while (kill(pong, 0)) {
      if (errno != ESRCH)
        err(-1, "kill start"); // exit
      usleep(1000);
      cnt++;
      if (cnt > 1000)
        err(0, "no partner"); // exit
    }
    printf("parent starts ping-pong (%d aditional attempts to see partner)\n",
           cnt);
    fflush(stdout); // important, if stdout redirect to file
    cnt = 1;
    for (;;) {
      write(fd[1], &cnt, sizeof(cnt));
      //      sleep(1);
      kill(pong, SIGUSR1);
      sigsuspend(&old);
      read(fd[0], &cnt, sizeof(cnt));
      printf("parent %d\n", cnt++); fflush(stdout);
    }
    exit(0); // not reached
  }

  puts("child ready");
  for (;;) {
    sigsuspend(&old);
    read(fd[0], &cnt, sizeof(cnt));
    printf("child %d\n", cnt++); fflush(stdout);
    write(fd[1], &cnt, sizeof(cnt));
    //    sleep(1);
    kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
  }    

}
```

Что непонятно, спрашивайте.